# JProfiler in Docker/Kubernetes startup error

Tags: jprofiler

I have bundled the JProfiler 12 agent in my application Docker image. The JVM starts with:

```
-agentpath:/deployment/jprofiler12/bin/linux-x64/libjprofilerti.so=port=8849,nowait
```

When my application starts, I see the following error message:

```
#################################################################
JVMSHRC226E Error opening shared class cache file 
JVMSHRC336E Port layer error code = -102
JVMSHRC337E Platform error message: Permission denied
JVMSHRC840E Failed to start up the shared cache.
JVMSHRC686I Failed to startup shared class cache. Continue without using it as -Xshareclasses:nonfatal is specified
JProfiler> Protocol version 64
JProfiler> Thread status info workaround enabled.
JProfiler> OpenJ9 JVMTI version 1.1 detected.
JProfiler> Java 11 detected.
JProfiler> Don't wait for frontend to connect.
JProfiler> 64-bit library
JProfiler> Could not locate the config file.
JProfiler> Please specify config=[config filename].
JProfiler> If you are running JProfiler's frontend on a different
JProfiler> machine you have to copy the file jprofiler_config.xml to this
JProfiler> computer. The file is located in $HOME/.jprofiler12 or
JProfiler> in C:\Users\[username]\.jprofiler12.
```

I have couple questions, I can't find documentation for in the startup help:
https://www.ej-technologies.com/resources/jprofiler/v/12.0/help/doc/main/profiling.html

Is there location where I could download a sample jprofiler_config.xml file?
Anyone would have an example of sending config=[config filename]?

Answer (score 1):

You can export such a file from the JProfiler GUI by invoking

```
Session->Export Session Settings
```

from the main menu and selecting a single session in the list of available sessions.